# Severity 17 error in SQL Server 2014 after upgrade

Tags: sql, sql-server, error-handling, sql-server-2014-express, database-cursor

I have a process that runs on an old desktop PC running SQL Server 2008 R2 that takes 1 day 22 hours to complete (Windows Server 8 - Intel Xenon E5530@ S2.4 GHZ. 3.91 GB RAM).

In an attempt to speed this up I have acquired a test version of SQL Server 2014 running on Windows Server 2012 (Xeon Silver 4116 CPU 2.10GHz with 24 GB RAM).

When I execute the previously slow running stored procedure on the new server I get the following error:

> Msg 18054, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_ServiceAlgorithimV2_Stage1, Line 60 [Batch Start Line 3]
>   Error 1653, severity 17, state 1 was raised, but no message with that error  number was found in sys.messages.  If error is larger than 50000, make sure the user-defined message is added using sp_addmessage.

I cannot seem to find out what this error means and what I can do about it.

The stored procedure in question cursors over 37426615 rows, using `CURSOR FOR`.

Inside the cursor, I take a `varchar` from the row and use it in fulltext query on a table that contains 336 rows.

I then store the matches in a temp table `@Table` the make decision based on the number of rows returned and `DELETE FROM @Table`.

The issue can’t be with the FT catalogue as at the point the error was raised 5,674,478 had been found and written to a non temporary table:

```
DECLARE @tempT TABLE (ID INT, ServiceID INT)    

DECLARE @ID INT, @service VARCHAR(500), @serviceid INT,
        @categoryid INT, @TopCategoryid INT, @NumResults INT,
        @ServiceName VARCHAR(500), @sql VARCHAR(4000), 
        @weight_value FLOAT, @weight_term VARCHAR(150),
        @sqlIsABout VARCHAR(4000), @supplier VARCHAR(150)

IF(@NumRows IS NULL)
    SET @NumRows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Spend)

DECLARE db_cursorCat CURSOR STATIC FOR
    --get all spend items that have not been allocated
    SELECT TOP (@NumRows) S.SpendID, S.Service, S.Supplier
    FROM Spend S 
    WHERE ISNULL(dbo.RegExReplace( Service,  '[^A-Za-z ,]+', ' '), '')!=''
    --AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SpendServiceType_Temp T WHERE T.Spendid = S.SpendID) 

/* Loop over spend items */
OPEN db_cursorCat   

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursorCat INTO @ID, @service, @supplier

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN 
    /* strip non-alphanumeric chars from search string*/
    SET @service = ISNULL(dbo.RegExReplace(LTRIM(@service),  '[^A-Za-z ,]+', ' '), '')

    IF @service != ''
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @tempT(ID, ServiceID)
            /* Run free text search on service types using the supplied service  adn insert results into temp table */
            SELECT @ID, S.ServiceTypeID
            FROM ServiceType S
            WHERE FREETEXT (ServiceType, @service)  

            /*check if only result has been found*/  
            SET @NumResults = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tempT)

            IF (@NumResults = 1)
            BEGIN
                /* Insert found service for THIS spend items */
                SET @serviceid = (SELECT TOP 1 ServiceID FROM  @tempT) 
                --
                INSERT INTO dbo.SpendServiceType(SpendID, ServiceTypeID)
                    SELECT @ID, @serviceid
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                                      FROM dbo.SpendServiceType ST  
                                      WHERE ST.SpendID = @ID 
                                        AND ST.ServiceTypeID = @serviceid)
           END
           ELSE
           BEGIN
               /* Add Spend item and found services to table for future processing */
               INSERT INTO [dbo].[SpendServiceType_Temp]([Spendid],[ServiceTypeid])
                   SELECT ID, Serviceid
                   FROM @tempT T
                   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                                     FROM dbo.SpendServiceType ST 
                                     WHERE T.ID = ST.SpendID 
                                       AND T.ServiceID = ST.ServiceTypeID)
           END

           /*delete temp table ready for next iteration*/
           DELETE FROM @tempT

           SET @service = ''
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursorCat INTO @ID, @service, @supplier
    END

    CLOSE db_cursorCat   
    DEALLOCATE db_cursorCat
END
```

Does anyone know what the error actually means and how I can attempt to debug it?

I understand from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-error-severities?view=sql-server-2017) that Severity Level 17 errors

"Indicate software errors that cannot be corrected by the user. Inform your system administrator of the problem."

but that is of no use to me.

Why does this work in SQL Server 2008 but not in SQL Server 2014?

[link to SQL on DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wxSXzGLmwiwfErPS6ezkQs/1)

Comment: Can you post the procedure in question please

Comment: The stored proc is too big to put in here, I will upload it somewhere and link to it

Comment: Too big? As in too may characters?

Comment: Here is the SQL 
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wxSXzGLmwiwfErPS6ezkQs/1

Comment: Probably the problem isn't in the procedure itself. Could be a trigger on any of the tables worked on. From the error message I'd suspect there is some [`RAISERROR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) somewhere with a message ID not in [`sys.messages`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/messages-for-errors-catalog-views-sys-messages?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Thanks for the reply however I never use triggers or RAISERROR and no such thing existed on the old version.

Comment: I have attempted to remove the cursor and utitlize more the 24GB of memory on this dedicated server by putting the Full TEXT search into a udf but I get exactly the same error

[Link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5o7uWgtx19kpvZpcbGw7hS/0)